# Importing obj file with a large offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, file-type

I have a series of obj files which were produced by photogrammetry by my coworkers who specialize in dealing with GIS (Geographic Information Systems) data. The first few data points in the files look something like:

```
v 445077.679 4460688.700 61.371 
v 445077.340 4460686.317 61.367 
v 445077.296 4460686.024 61.416
```

I believe the file is valid because I can open the files in an online viewer and I get what I expect to see using the viewer at http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/ObjViewer:
[image: Online view using http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/ObjViewer]

When I open the same file in Blender, Unity or Unreal Engine, the object is very far from the world origin. I can center it by moving the origin to the center of mass and then resetting the object location, but when I recenter the object I always see something that looks like: [image: Image from Blender]

What am I doing wrong, or what could be wrong with my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem with these files is the large offset combined with 32-bit float values. In this case the objects all use the same geographic origin, probably at a lat/long of 0.000N/0.000E

Nearly all 3D graphics programs use 32-bit floating point values to store each points location, and the combination of the offset and the 32-bit value causes some of the precision to be lost. 32-bit floats have about 7 decimal digits of precision, so the offset of 4460688 in the example file completely dominates, and effectively cuts the model from 1mm resolution to 1m resolution data. The reason for the long triangles is that there is more data lost in one direction due to the asymmetry of the offset.

The solution is to apply some offset to bring the objects close to the origin BEFORE importing them with the 3D software.
I wrote a quick python script that can help with this: https://gitlab.umich.edu/lsa-ts-rsp/xr-shiftOBJ/-/blob/main/shiftOBJ.py

```
import re  # regex


def shiftFile(inFileName, outFileName, offset):
    with open(inFileName) as myInFile:
        with open(outFileName, 'w') as myOutFile:
            for line in myInFile:
                myOutFile.write(shiftLine(line, offset))


def shiftLine(inLine, offset):
    #if a line is a vertex then apply the shift and drop vertex colors
    lineRegex = re.compile('v (\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)')
    m = lineRegex.match(inLine)
    if m and len(m.groups()) >= 3:
        outLine = 'v ' + "{:.3f}".format(float(m.groups()[0]) + offset[0]) + ' ' + "{:.3f}".format(float(m.groups()[1]) + offset[1]) + ' ' + "{:.3f}".format(float(m.groups()[2]) + offset[2]) + '\n'
        return outLine
    else:
        return inLine


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inFile = '/Users/crstock/Documents/Unreal Projects/Olynthos Data/B88DW18.obj'
    outFile = '/Users/crstock/Documents/Unreal Projects/Olynthos Data/B88DW18_shifted.obj'
    offset = [-445070, -4460680, -59.0]
    shiftFile(inFile, outFile, offset)
```

This applies an offset to all vertex lines and leaves the other lines alone. By using the same offset values for multiple input files you can maintain the relative shift so that related objects fit together appropriately.